# Activity state instance - insights?

Tags: android

I have a question regarding where the saved state instance of an activity is stored, internally.
Since it's possible to restore even when the process is killed, I expect that Android OS stores the data somewhere else (other than app's process memory space).

I'm asking because I have a sessionId (in app memory only) which is sensitive and I have a requirement not to store it in permanent storage.
Would the state instance of the Activity fall under this category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Will 'Bundle savedInstanceState' be alive after Application is being killed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837595/will-bundle-savedinstancestate-be-alive-after-application-is-being-killed).

In AOSP 4.4.2, the saved instance states are stored in the system process's memory.

Comment: Thanks, I've read that question but my main question was covered from your 2nd line. Is there any reference for that, or indication from source code?

Comment: Yes - you can take a look at how ActivityManagerService, ActivityRecord and ActivityStack keep track of the stored state (they call it icicle internally). Sources are at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.4.2_r2/services/java/com/android/server/am/